# SharePoint 2016 Search Service

Tags: search, 2016, searchserviceapplication

I am installing a SharePoint 2016 farm, 1 webapp and 1 app server.

With this in mind I was thinking about where to put the elements of the Search;

Admin Component, Query Component, Crawl Component, Search Query and Site Settings Component, Index Component, Content Processing component and Analytics processing component.

As I have not separated search I was unsure whether I should just install these all on both servers or only put them in one or separate them between the two i.e query on web app crawl index on app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend everything except the Query Component should go on your app server, so as not to overload the web front end.

Creating a secondary backup copy of the Search Index (i.e. the one stored on disk) on the WFE is also a good idea, if you can, to increase fault tolerance.

Remember to have both servers configured via HOSTS to point all your web apps that will be crawled back to 127.0.0.1 - this saves round-trip time when a crawl is processed.